# Font-awesome icon is not appearing inside the textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to fit the font-awesome icon within the textbox, but I was unable to do so. I tried to decrease the width of the textbox but still its appearing a line below. Can you please guide me to fix my mistake in this. I am attaching the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="primaryName">PRIMARY NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryName" name="primaryName" placeholder="Name" >
        <div class="input-group-prepend bg-white">
                <span class="input-group-text border-left-0 rounded-right bg-light" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="primaryPhone">PRIMARY PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Phone number">
    </div>
</div>
```

### The output on the screen is as below :

[image]

### I want the output to be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] or a link to Bootply or something? Also you have got `fas fa-user` should be `fa fa-user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issues are:

1. You have a wrong class name: `fas fa-user` should be `fa fa-user`.
2. You don't have `input-group` `<div>` to enclose.

Fixing both above will fix it.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="primaryName">PRIMARY NAME</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryName" name="primaryName" placeholder="Name" >
      <div class="input-group-prepend bg-white">
        <span class="input-group-text border-left-0 rounded-right bg-light" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="primaryPhone">PRIMARY PHONE NUMBER</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Phone number">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @METALHEAD `fas` is correct if we are using the V5 of fontawesome : https://jsfiddle.net/v6hpx8tc/4/ so only the wrapping div is the error. Also in the screenshot the icon is showing which confirm this

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your valuable reply. Will keep it in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is not wrong. It is working with latest Font Awesome versions ( > v5.0).

**Font Awesome 5**,

```
Syntax - <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
Font Awesome 5 CDN - https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css
```

**Font Awesome 4**,

```
Syntax - <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
Font Awesome 4 CDN - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

If you need any clarification, let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: @ METALHEAD, It's my pleasure :)